# Error: command \DH unavailable in encoding T5. \end{frame}

Tags: errors

When I compile my beamer it says that I have some problem with \end{frame} (like the photo I up here) but I don't know why. I still compile my beamer well last hour, but now I can't compile it anymore. Please help me. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, add a minimal example of code. On the other hand, Vietnamese uses Đ (U+0110 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH STROKE) rather than Ð (U+00D0 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ETH). They are distinct characters, even if their printed appearance is the same. Remove all those useless `\displaystyle`,  `\left` and `\right` commands in the shown code.

Comment: I have remove it. And then, it works again but now it's not.